# warning when running ddd in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ddd-debugger

I've just installed ddd on Ubuntu 14.04 LTE. If I run it on the command line, I get the following warnings:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/projects/myproject$ ddd
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
(Annoyed?  Try 'Edit->Preferences->General->Suppress X Warnings'!)
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-100-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-180-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-symbol-*-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-adobe-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
Warning: Could not load font "-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-*-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*", using font "fixed" instead
```

It seems like there are a lot of people are experiencing this problem, but I wasn't able to find a solution. This is based on the google search.

Any help in resolving the issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a known bug in ddd related to this. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/ddd/2012-05/msg00001.html. Basically it makes hard coded assumptions about what version of the fonts is installed. These assumptions do not work for all distros.

For Debian systems installing xfonts-100dpi and then logging out and back in should eliminate these messages. If it doesn't you may be affected by the above issue.

Answer (score 4):

I installed the xfonts-100dpi package noted above. After a reboot
(Logout might have worked, but I didn't try that.), 
the problem with ddd had resolved itself (into adieu. 8^}).

This was on Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

Here's the command required:

sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi

Perhaps the Ubuntu people should either install those fonts automatically,
or make ddd drag the fonts along when you install ddd.